# Bacula: Writing backup fails

Tags: centos, centos7, bacula

I installed bacula 7 on Cent OS 7 according to this howto: http://www.backupcentral.com/phpBB2/two-way-mirrors-of-external-mailing-lists-3/bacula-25/howto-install-bacula-7-on-centos-7-fresh-install-126395/ .

Now I would like to backup a server but the job is stuck at `is waiting for a mount request`.

The director shows the following messages:

```
31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: mount.c:212 Open of file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: mount.c:212 Open of file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: mount.c:212 Open of file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: mount.c:212 Open of file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: label.c:362 Open file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Warning: mount.c:212 Open of file device "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) Volume "Remote-0002" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:172 Could not open(/var/bacula/backups/Remote-0002,CREATE_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=Keine Berechtigung 

31-Dez 15:42 bacula-sd JobId 6: Please mount append Volume "Remote-0002" or label a new one for: 
Job: myserver-db.2015-12-31_15.42.23_03 
Storage: "FileStorage" (/var/bacula/backups) 
Pool: RemoteFile 
Media type: File
```

The error `Keine Berechtigung` means `Permission denied`.

Well, but there is a directory `/var/bacula/backups/` with the following rights: `drwxr-xr-x. 2 bacula bacula`

Comment: What happens if you just try creating a file in that directory when logged in as `bacula`? Something like `sudo -u bacula touch /var/bacula/backups/tempfile`

Answer (score 2):

The correct permissions for the files in the storage daemon are bacula:disk.
So

```
chown -R bacula:disk /var/bacula/backups
```